# Why function expression and function declaration have different inference results for a variable?

Tags: typescript

I have a variable and three function:

```
const a: string | number = 3

function b(){
  console.log(a)               // string | number 
}
const c = function (){
  console.log(a)               // number
}
const d = () => {
  console.log(a)               // number
}
```

When I hovered the word `a` in function `b`, what I got is `string | number`;

When I hovered the word `a` in function `c`, what I got is `number`;

When I hovered the word `a` in function `d`, what I got is `number`

But isn't `a` a constant? After the first time it was assigned the value `3`, `a` have been infered to become a `number` type. Why in function `b` it still have a chance to become a `string` type?

Comment: Fascinating question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because of function hoisting. In theory, `b` could be called before `a` has its value definitely assigned:

```typescript
b(); // <=====
const a: string | number = 3

function b(){
  console.log(a)               // string | number 
}
const c = function (){
  console.log(a)               // number
}
const d = () => {
  console.log(a)               // number
}
```

Neither `c` nor `d` can be called from there, they aren't assigned until *after* `a` is definitely assigned.

From a runtime perspective, the call to `b` would throw when trying to access `a` because `a` would be in the temporal dead zone, but from a type perspective, it would be before TypeScript knew it was a `number`.

Comment: It makes sense. But if I use `let a: string | number = 3`, why the hovered result in function `c` is `string | number` instead of `number`? After all, when I hovered the `console.log(a)` in global scope, the result is `number`. Is it because `a` is a variable instead of a constant which makes it has a chance a become a string in a function?

Comment: @Chor - Right. With `let`, TypeScript can't narrow the type because the value may be changed. But with a `const`, we (and TypeScript) know the value can't be changed once it's definitely assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because in JS/TS, functions' names (and types) are declared before any values are assigned to variables/constants. At the time `function b`'s type is evaluated, only the declared type of `a` is known, i.e. `string | number`. By the time `c` and `d` are assigned to, `a` is known to be a constant `number` value of 3.

Answer (score 0):

In `js`, functions are first-class citizens, so functions directly declared in `js` will be brought to the forefront. If you try the following code, all `a`s will prompt `string | number`, [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwBQEoDeAoRiIIDOcANgKYB0JcA5qgIbp7MuuID07ihUATjGBqIAPojAgAtsjK9E2AL7YCYHvkQBeRKEiwEiDDjzLi5KrQZM2Vjlx79BIsZOmyFSolEQATDfqbqAPkRDfCJSSmo6RmsrTm4%20ASFRcSkZOUVjT3oALnj7JKdU2U0AZiA)

```
function b(){
  console.log(a)               // string | number 
}
const c = function (){
  console.log(a)               // string | number 
}
const d = () => {
  console.log(a)               // string | number 
}
const a: string | number = 3
```

Comment: @DustInCompetent - Correct (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69971847/157247)). At runtime, it would be an error because `a` would be in the temporal dead zone. But from a *type* perspective, it makes sense.